# How can I convert an ArrayList to JSON Object to be able to iterate through it in Java?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to loop through a json object I pulled through the web but I can't seem to convert it from a string to a jsonarray or jsonobject. I want to be able to use a for loop to iterate through it and then conditionally output names based on some values.

This is a simple java program to demonstrate pulling json data from a web api and then looping through it.

Here's the code:

```
  public static List<String> getUsernames(int threshold) throws IOException {
        List<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();

        BufferedReader reader;
        String line;
        StringBuffer responseContent = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("url to json api");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //Request method
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

            int status = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(status);

            if (status > 299) {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseContent.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            } else {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    usernames.add(line);
                }

//                String json = new Gson().toJson(usernames);
//
//                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json);
//                System.out.println(json);


                Gson gson = new Gson();
                

                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return usernames;
    }
```

Comment: You already put the usernames into an ArrayList. Why not iterate over that List? Why do you want to convert the List to a JsonArray?

Comment: I want to be able to extract data from json to variables so I can use that to conditionally output names to usernames. Wouldn't it be easier to use a json array when dealing with json data?

Comment: I assumed because your list is called `usernames` that it would be a list containing usernames. If you are just reading in a single JSON-String then saving every line as an Element in an ArrayList is probably where you went wrong. Just save/append the JSON-Data in a single String and then try to parse that String as JSON.

Comment: I have the data as a string in responseContent now but how can I parse string as JSON?

Comment: Could you please provide what response string you are getting ?

Answer (score -2):

```
 List<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
    usernames.add("Hibernate");
    usernames.add("spring");
    
    JSONArray jsonStr = new JSONArray().put(usernames);

    for (Object values: jsonStr) {
        System.out.println(values);
    }
```